# How to access the current Subversion build number?

Tags: svn

How can you automatically import the latest build/revision number in subversion?

The goal would be to have that number visible on your webpage footer like SO does.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
svn info <Repository-URL>
```

or

```
svn info --xml <Repository-URL>
```

Then look at the result. For xml, parse /info/entry/@revision for the revision of the repository (151 in this example) or /info/entry/commit/@revision for the revision of the last commit against this path (133, useful when working with tags):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<info>
<entry
   kind="dir"
   path="cmdtools"
   revision="151">
<url>http://myserver/svn/stumde/cmdtools</url>
<repository>
<root>http://myserver/svn/stumde</root>
<uuid>a148ce7d-da11-c240-b47f-6810ff02934c</uuid>
</repository>
<commit
   revision="133">
<author>mstum</author>
<date>2008-07-12T17:09:08.315246Z</date>
</commit>
</entry>
</info>
```

I wrote a tool ([cmdnetsvnrev](http://www.stum.de/various-tools/cmdtools/), source code included) for myself which replaces the Revision in my AssemblyInfo.cs files. It's limited to that purpose though, but generally svn info and then processing is the way to go.

Answer (score 33):

Have your build process call the [svnversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnversion.re.html) command, and embed its output into generated {source|binaries}. This will not only give the current revision (as many other examples here do), but its output string will also tell whether a build is being done in a mixed tree or a tree which doesn't exactly match the revision number in question (ie. a tree with local changes).

With a standard tree:

```
$ svnversion
3846
```

With a modified tree:

```
$ echo 'foo' >> project-ext.dtd
$ svnversion                   
3846M
```

With a mixed-revision, modified tree:

```
$ (cd doc; svn up >/dev/null 2>/dev/null)
$ svnversion
3846:4182M
```

Comment: any idea how you can get it to list the versions of any externals aswell?

Comment: @ShoeLace - Not with svnversion, sadly -- but a tiny bit of grep and awk work on svn status --verbose will get you what you're looking for.

Comment: @ShoeLace, ...btw, to update that -- today, I'd use `svn status --verbose --xml`, with XMLStarlet or an XSLT template postprocessing.

Answer (score 19):

The [`svnversion`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnversion.re.html) command is the correct way to do this.  It outputs the revision number your entire working copy is at, or a range of revisions if your working copy is mixed (e.g. some directories are up to date and some aren't).  It will also indicate if the working copy has local modifications.  For example, in a rather unclean working directory:

```
$ svnversion
662:738M
```

The $Revision$ keyword doesn't do what you want: it only changes when the containing file does.  The Subversion book gives [more detail](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html).  The "svn info" command also doesn't do what you want, as it only tells you the state of your current directory, ignoring the state of any subdirectories.  In the same working tree as the previous example, I had some subdirectories which were newer than the directory I was in, but "svn info" doesn't notice:

```
$ svn info
... snip ...
Revision: 662
```

It's easy to incorporate svnversion into your build process, so that each build gets the revision number in some runtime-accessible form.  For a Java project, for example, I had our makefile dump the svnversion output into a .properties file.

Comment: Please accept my apologies for the now-reversed downvote. At the time, I considered this near-plagarism -- but it does add new content (explaining the limitations of `$Revision$`, suggesting use of a makefile, etc) without copying any text verbatim, so it's entirely legitimate as its own answer.

Answer (score 12):

Add svn:keywords to the SVN properties of the source file:

```
svn:keywords Revision
```

Then in the source file include:

```
private const string REVISION = "$Revision$";
```

The revision will be updated with the revision number at the next commit to (e.g.) `"$Revision: 4455$"`. You can parse this string to extract just the revision number.

Comment: A question about that: I found that $Revision$ is only updated if that particular file changes, otherwise it stays untouched. Is there a way to force-update $Revision$ on every checkin/out, regardless if the file was modified in the last commit or not?

Comment: No, you have to make a file change and commit for this to work. I've always just included the REVISION const in the file that contains the version number or release notes that is normally updated prior to a release anyway.

Comment: How would you do this if the file is a .js file?

Answer (score 7):

If you have tortoise SVN you can use SubWCRev.exe

Create a file called:

RevisionInfo.tmpl

```
SvnRevision = $WCREV$;
```

Then execute this command:

```
SubWCRev.exe . RevisionInfo.tmpl RevisionInfo.txt
```

It will create a file ReivisonInfo.txt with your revision number as follows:

```
SvnRevision = 5000;
```

But instead of using the .txt you could use whatever source file you want, and have access to the reivsion number within your source code.

Answer (score 5):

You don't say what programming language/framework you're using. Here's how to do it in Python using [PySVN](http://pysvn.tigris.org)

```
import pysvn
repo = REPOSITORY_LOCATION
rev = pysvn.Revision( pysvn.opt_revision_kind.head )
client = pysvn.Client()
info = client.info2(repo,revision=rev,recurse=False)
revno = info[0][1].rev.number # revision number as an integer
```

Answer (score 5):

Using c# and SharpSvn (from http://sharpsvn.net) the code would be:

```
//using SharpSvn;
long revision = -1;
using(SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
{
  client.Info(path,
    delegate(object sender, SvnInfoEventArgs e)
    {
       revision = e.Revision;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my latest project I solved this problem by using several tools, SVN, NAnt, and a custom NAnt task.

1. Use NAnt to execute `svn info --xml ./svnInfo.xml`
2. Use NAnt to pull the revision number from the xml file with `<xmlpeek>`
3. Use a custom NAnt task to update the AssemblyVersion attribute in the AssemblyInfo.cs file with the latest with the version number (e.g., major.minor.maintenance, revision) before compiling the project.

The version related sections of my build script look like this:

```
<!-- Retrieve the current revision number for the working directory -->
<exec program="svn" commandline='info --xml' output="./svnInfo.xml" failonerror="false"/>
<xmlpeek file="./svnInfo.xml" xpath="info/entry/@revision" property="build.version.revision" if="${file::exists('./svnInfo.xml')}"/>

<!-- Custom NAnt task to replace strings matching a pattern with a specific value -->
<replace file="${filename}" 
         pattern="AssemblyVersion(?:Attribute)?\(\s*?\&quot;(?&lt;version&gt;(?&lt;major&gt;[0-9]+)\.(?&lt;minor&gt;[0-9]+)\.(?&lt;build&gt;[0-9]+)\.(?&lt;revision&gt;[0-9]+))\&quot;\s*?\)" 
         value="AssemblyVersion(${build.version})"
         outfile="${filename}"/>
```

The credit for the regular expression goes to: http://code.mattgriffith.net/UpdateVersion/. However, I found that UpdateVersion did not meet my needs as the pin feature was broken in the build I had. Hence the custom NAnt task.

If anyone is interested in the code, for the custom NAnt `replace` task let me know. Since this was for a work related project I will need to check with management to see if we can release it under a friendly (free) license.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a hint, how you might use **Netbeans**' capabilities to
create **custom ant tasks** which would generate scm-version.txt:

Open your **build.xml** file, and add following code right **after**
`<import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>`

```
<!-- STORE SUBVERSION BUILD STRING -->
<target name="-pre-compile">
  <exec executable="svnversion"
    output="${src.dir}/YOUR/PACKAGE/NAME/scm-version.txt"/>
</target>
```

Now, Netbeans strores the Subversion version string
to **scm-version.txt** everytime you make **clean/build**.

You can read the file during runtime by doing:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("scm-version.txt"); // ...
```

Don't forget to mark the file **scm-version.txt** as **svn:ignore**.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails I use this snippet in my environment.rb which gives me a constant I can use throughout the application (like in the footer of an application layout).

```
SVN_VERSION  = IO.popen("svn info").readlines[4].strip.split[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can run 'svn info' to determine the current revision number, and you could probably extract that pretty easily with a regex, like "Revision: ([0-9]+)".

Comment: `svn info | sed -n 's/^Revision: //p'`

Answer (score 1):

If you are running under GNU/Linux, cd to the working copy's directory and run:

```
svn -u status | grep Status\ against\ revision: | awk '{print $4}'
```

From my experience, svn info does not give reliable numbers after renaming directories.

Comment: And as always, `grep foo | awk '{ bar }'` can most usefully be refactored to `awk '/foo/ { bar }'` --  `svn -u status | awk '/Status against revision:/ { print $4 }'`

Answer (score 0):

You want the Subversion **info** subcommand, as follows:

```
$ svn info .
Path: .
URL: http://trac-hacks.org/svn/tracdeveloperplugin/trunk
Repository Root: http://trac-hacks.org/svn
Repository UUID: 7322e99d-02ea-0310-aa39-e9a107903beb
Revision: 4190
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: coderanger
Last Changed Rev: 3397
Last Changed Date: 2008-03-19 00:49:02 -0400 (Wed, 19 Mar 2008)
```

In this case, there are two revision numbers:  4190 and 3397.  4190 is the last revision number for the repository, and 3397 is the revision number of the last change to the subtree that this workspace was checked out from.  You can specify a path to a workspace, or a URL to a repository.

A C# fragment to extract this under Windows would look something like this:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"svn.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"info {0}", path);
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.Start();

// Parse the svn info output for something like "Last Changed Rev: 1234"
using (StreamReader output = process.StandardOutput)
{
    Regex LCR = new Regex(@"Last Changed Rev: (\d+)");

    string line;
    while ((line = output.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Match match = LCR.Match(line);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            revision = match.Groups[1].Value;
        }
    }
}
```

(In my case, we use the Subversion revision as part of the version number for assemblies.)

Answer (score 0):

I use the [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) project which has a tool to retrieve the SVN revision number and add it to your AssemblyInfo.vb.  You can then use reflection to retrieve this string to display it in your UI.

Here's a [full blog post with instructions](http://solutionmania.com/2009/8/28/automatically-adding-svn-revision-numbers-to-assemblies).

Answer (score 0):

if you're using svnant, you can use wcVersion, which duplicates svnveresion and returns digestible values. see:
http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svn.html#wcVersion

Answer (score 0):

I created an [SVN version plug-in](http://happyturtle.codeplex.com/) for the [Build Version Increment](http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/) project on CodePlex.  This SVN plug-in will pull the latest change revision number from your working copy and allow you to use that in your version number, which should accomplish exactly what you're trying to do.  Build Version Increment is pretty flexible and will allow you to set up how the versioning is done in a number of ways.

BVI only works with Visual Studio, but since you're using Asp.Net, that won't be a problem.  It doesn't require writing any code or editing xml, so yay!