# BuildNumber not generated with buildnumber-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven

In my parent pom I have

```xml
<build>
 <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                <goal>create</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
            <configuration>
                <doCheck>true</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

In a child module run a java Main class with the above default properties: **buildName** and **scmBranch**:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
    <execution>
        <id>my-execution</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        </executions>
            <configuration>
            <executable>java</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-classpath</argument>
                        <classpath />
                        <argument>${MyMainClass}</argument>
                        <argument>test-${scmBranch}-${buildNumber}</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
```

But the variables are never substituted/expanded in my main class. Any ideas?

From the documentation:

```
required: false
type: java.lang.String
expression: ${maven.buildNumber.buildNumberPropertyName}
default: buildNumber

You can rename the buildNumber property name to another 
 property name if desired.
```

As I understand the **buildNumber** is a property provided when you include the buildnumber-maven-plugin

Comment: Where are the properties scmBranch and buildNumber defined? Could you paste that code too?

Comment: As I understand they are provided when you use the plugin

Comment: Do you have the `<scm>` block defined in your pom? That is required for the build number plugin to know how to talk to your source control system. Also, I recommend you set a value for `<revisionOnScmFailure>`, so you can easily see a bad value when something goes wrong, like `<revisionOnScmFailure>didn't work!</revisionOnScmFailure>`. Also, can you please paste the output of maven? The build number plugin should be logging some information about what it is doing when invoked.

Comment: Can you remove the definition of the life cycle phase and use the default life cycle phase of the plugin and recheck? How have you calle mvn ? **mvn clean package** ?

Comment: Removing from life cycle does nothing and yes I build with mvn clean package

Comment: Defining a dummy scm seems to be the way to go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115765/is-it-possible-to-use-maven-buildnumber-plugin-to-generate-build-number-without but how do I make it install into .m2 using the build number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your parent pom, you have not defined the [pluginManagement](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management) tag. Without it, your child module does not inherit the plugins you have defined, they are used by the parent pom only. This is what you need to add to the **parent pom**:

```
<build>
    <!-- plugins used by this POM and all inheriting POMs -->
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <doCheck>true</doCheck>
                    <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- other plugins -->
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Now your child module has access to the buildnumber-maven-plugin.

Comment: Tried this proposal, but it did not work. ${buildNumber} is not propagated, stays "null".

Comment: Hi, do you declare buildnumber-maven-plugin in your child's <plugins>? You'd only need to redeclare groupId and artifactId, the rest is inherited.

Comment: After pulling, reorganising, messing etc with my pom's, I must take my previous statement back. Your example works great and I'm now enjoying commit id in all child modules jar's in build.properties.

Comment: Great! Feel free to edit my answer with any missing information. Thanks!