# How to get Maven to automatically use git status as part of version number?

Tags: git, maven

This question is a narrower version of the broader [Automatically incrementing a build number in a Java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988405/automatically-incrementing-a-build-number-in-a-java-project)

Specifically I want Maven to generate versions of the format `major.minor.sequence` where `major.minor` are hard-coded in the `pom.xml` but the `sequence` number is obtained from the output of the command `git rev-list HEAD --count`. I also want to append the string "-WIP" if the `git status` does not contain the words `nothing to commit, working tree clean`.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you aware of the command [git describe](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe)? Sounds like your use case might make use of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For such thing there is a solution in [Maven 3.5.0](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/release-notes.html) you can use `${sha1}`, `${changelist}`, `${revision}` for such purposes. Either a single one of them or you can combine them together.

```xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache</artifactId>
    <version>18</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.ci</groupId>
  <artifactId>ci-parent</artifactId>
  <name>First CI Friendly</name>
  <version>${revision}${sha1}${changelist}</version>
  ...
  <properties>
    <revision>1.3.1</revision>
    <changelist>-SNAPSHOT</changelist>
    <sha1/>
  </properties>
</project>
```

By using the above you can simply build the application using:

```
mvn clean package
```

But also it's possible to do it like this:

```
mvn -Drevision=2.7.1 clean package
```

Based on your example you can use:

```
mvn -Dsha1=-XXXX clean package
```

where the `XXXX` can be replaced with information extracted from Git (describe) or even better with informations from Jenkins (GIT_REVISION etc.).

Very important hint use the flatten-maven-plugin as described in the in the [ci friendly documentation page](http://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html).

Answer (score -1):

Well, I would think if you really want it to work this way, you'd have to write a wrapper around your `mvn` command that runs the appropriate `git` commands, calculates the version string suffix, and passes it as a `-Dversion.suffix=` option when calling the real `mvn` executable.

(Then in your pom you'd set the version to something like `3.7.${version.suffix}`.)

You probably should be sure to avoid human-targetted interfaces (like the string "nothing to commit, working tree clean") if you can find equivalent interfaces that are intended for scripting.  (For example, check out the output formats for the `--porcelain` option in the `git status` documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status)

That said, are you sure this is a good idea?  There is no guarantee that the number of commits is a strictly-increasing value, and if you have more than one developer you could end up having different versions with the same version number.  Maven's `-SNAPSHOT` convention doesn't give you the specificity you're looking for, but exists more or less to acknowledge that the specificity you're looking for is usually more trouble than it's worth...

Comment: This will produce warnings during your builds

Comment: @khmarbaise - Yes, variable version numbers will create a warning.  And as I noted, it isn't something I recommend.  But it *is* the best way I see to do what was asked.  If you can think of a better way, post an answer.