# how can i version a java application between builds?

Tags: java, git, maven, build-automation

Currently, my Java applications have the same version on every build. I am using Maven, but I am not sure how to set up the workflow to add a version to the application on each build.

I imagine this works with my version control system? I am using git, does this mean I need git tags?

Thanks for any insights, I know it's a big question, but I am not sure where to get started.

Comment: A java application does not have inherent notion of version. Where is the version -- which currently does not change -- coming from?

Comment: There is probably a properties or manifest file that you need to update during your build.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690419/build-and-version-numbering-for-java-projects-ant-cvs-hudson

Comment: Also see [Setting Package Version Information](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/packageman.html) for properties in the manifest that can be retrieved at run-time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You start by setting your version to, for example, 1-SNAPSHOT.

Then you use the maven-release-plugin to release early and often.

In the interim, each snapshot gets a unique timestamp.

If you want to apply a version that isn't the official maven version, see the buildnumber-maven-plugin.

Answer (score 3):

I use this Maven plugin:

https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin

and get it to generate a `git.properties` file for me. This includes the commit id, comments, etc.

From there, you can do whatever you like. I have a properties page in my webapp that simply iterates over everything in `git.properties`. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use maven POM file to define versions. [Here](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates) is an explanation.

Also you can update versions using [this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/update-versions.html).