# Automatically insert the date?

Tags: date, build, codenameone

I'd like to automatically insert the date into the code
as part of the build process.  Is there some existing way
to do this?

If not, how could this be done?  One approach that occurs
to me is to add an ant step which writes a small source file
containing the date.

Answer (score 0):

We used something similar to [Build and Version Numbering for Java Projects (ant, cvs, hudson)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690419/build-and-version-numbering-for-java-projects-ant-cvs-hudson) when building Codename One itself. We didn't expose it in the library up until now but we use it in the designer and other tools.

It should be possible to expose something like this in the app using the [Properties](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/Properties.html) class.