# Including SVN head revision number in the manifest.mf

Tags: ant, build-process

I am creating a WAR file using Ant. When WAR is created it has MANIFEST.MF file with the default content :
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.4
Created-By: 1.7.0_07-b10 (Oracle Corporation).

So, when the WAR is created it should also have Build Revision Number/Head revision number of SVN and the MANIFEST.MF in the WAR should look like this:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.4
Created-By: 1.7.0_07-b10 (Oracle Corporation)
Revision: #Head Revision number

Comment: possible duplicate of [How best to store Subversion version information in EAR's?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171828/how-best-to-store-subversion-version-information-in-ears)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use `buildnumber-maven-plugin`. See this article for more details: http://manifests.jcabi.com/versioning.html

Also, see this post for more details: http://www.yegor256.com/2014/07/03/how-to-read-manifest-mf.html