# How to get from SVN the previous revision before the HEAD?

Tags: svn

I have the latest revision checked out to my working copy, but it's broken - it can't compiled.

How to get the previous revision before the head? And if it's broken too - the previous before the previous?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`svn update -r PREV`

[Here's a link to the documentation on revision keywords.](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.keywords)

If none of the keywords (HEAD, BASE, COMMITTED, or PREV) is exactly what you want, then just look in the log and find an explicit revision number to update to.

Answer (score 3):

`svn info http://[server]:[host]/myrepo` will give you the revision of the repository.

Then update your local copy with `svn update -r [revision-1] http://[server]:[host]/myrepo`

Answer (score 3):

If you know the revision number of a good build, then rather than stepping back-- from head until you find the revision that broke the build, you might use '[divide and conquer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm)' to find the problem.  If you've got any more than a few revisions since the last known good this will save you time.

Pseudo code:

```
known_good=whatever
known_bad=head_revision
start:
    candidate=(known_good + known_bad) / 2

    build candidate

    if success
        known_good=candidate
    else
        known_bad=candidate

    if (known_good + 1) == known_bad
        goto end

    go to start:
end:
```

Glossing over odd numbered revisions a bit there...

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to fetch the current revision number, decrease it by one and `svn update` to that revision until you find a build that works. I don't think Subversion can provide you much automated help here, because it can't know which revision will compile.

See these questions on how to get hold of the current revision number:

- [**SO # 1991526**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110175/how-to-access-the-current-subversion-build-number)
- [**SO # 110175**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110175/how-to-access-the-current-subversion-build-number)

Answer (score 0):

for TortoiseSVN using the context menu: `svn->Update to revision`

for command line use

```
svn update --revision svn://repo
```

If you really wanna be fancy about it, you can make a script where you give it the current revision number of HEAD and from there it goes down revisions until `make` (or whatever) doesn't return an error.