# How do I get the revision number before head in SVN

Tags: svn

I am new to source control and svn. I wanted to get the revision before head. Lets say that the head is at 900 and the revision before it is 885. I started by learning how to get the head first like this `svn info http://svn.repo1.com/trunk/app`. I saw a post which shows how to update my working copy to previous revision - [How to get from SVN the previous revision before the HEAD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052803/how-to-get-from-svn-the-previous-revision-before-the-head). I am only viewing the repository. I am never checking in anything. So the update command won't work for me. What can I do to just get the previous number ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I thought of better google search words - svn last 10 commit and got the missing piece in the puzzle.

```
svn log --limit 1  http://svn.repo1.com/trunk/app
```

This shows me the last one revision number. Is this okay ?