# SVN: How to tell revision number?

Tags: svn, deployment

We have a web application deployed to a server, which was done via an `svn update`. Now, I want to know what revision number was deployed to that server. What command do I use to get this information?

Also, once I get this revision number, I want to deploy that revision to another server. How do I do an `svn update` and specify a revision number?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access the current Subversion build number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110175/how-to-access-the-current-subversion-build-number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to launch svn info on the source directory:

```
svn info path/to/source | grep revision
```

And:

```
svn update -r revision
```

Comment: what is the source directory supposed to be? I am at the web root of the application. When I do a `pwd`, I get `/var/www/`. So, I tried this command: `svn info /var/www/ | grep revision`; I got nothing.

Comment: If the directory you're in is the directory which you want to get the version number for, a simple `svn info` should work.  If grep is failing for whatever reason, just look at it manually, it shouldn't be too hard to locate.

Comment: wouldn't that be `grep "^Revision"` ? or could it be svn-version-dependent ?

Answer (score 2):

`svnversion` is another option. In addition to showing you the current version of the checkout, it will also tell you whether any files are modified or if you have a mixed revision working copy (ie not all files are at the same revision).