# Prevent javascript from being cached in browser

Tags: javascript, caching, google-chrome

I'm currently working on a webapp and the Javascript is revised fairly often. However, the changes don't occur until the browser cache is refreshed manually. Is there a way to implement cache-refreshing automatically through code for Chrome? Thanks.

Comment: I never have this problem. Are you sure it's Chrome that is doing the caching, as opposed to your site?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put something like `?2352352` at the end of your JS file. So something like

```
<script src='myfile.js?20457207'></script>
```

Where the number randomizes, forcing the browser to think it's a different file.

Comment: This looks like a solution but I'm not sure what the implications are.  So we're currently using TortoiseSVN. Does anyone know if there's a way to automatically have TortoiseSVN prepend a comment with the version# of the commit every time a new version is committed?

Comment: You would just need to update the html `<script>` each time you change a version. Or, you should be able to google and find a way to access revision number. Which you could probably inject in place of the random int. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110175/how-to-access-the-current-subversion-build-number) may be useful.

Comment: A random number may be convenient during development, but in production a version number is a lot better, so the file can be cached as long as there is no new version. Using a random number, the  file will never be cached, and downloaded at each page view, even if the js file has not been changed.

Comment: Very true. A random int will force it to pull as new each time.