# Parse the output of command in a shell script and store the result in a variable

Tags: shell, cut, unix

When I execute the following `svn` command, I get the below output.

```
$ svn log -r 1:HEAD --limit 1 http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/bulk-delete
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r91525 | plugin-master | 2009-02-03 10:39:23 +0530 (Tue, 03 Feb 2009) | 1 line

adding bulk-delete by sudar
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am writing a shell script and I want to parse the output of the above command and get the revision number (r91525 in this case) and store it in a shell variable, so that I can use it in the subsequent commands.

I tried the cut command and was able to get the revision number in the second line, but the other lines were still appearing.

```
$ svn log -r 1:HEAD --limit 1 http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/bulk-delete | cut -f1 -d'|'
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r91525 

adding bulk-delete by sudar
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Question: How to retrieve the revision number and store in a shell variable, so that I can use it in the subsequent commands?

Comment: if what you need is the latest revision, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/111173/393701

Comment: @SirDarius No, I don't want the latest version. I want the version in which this directory was introduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed` for this.

```
  svn log --limit 1 | sed -n -e 's/^\(r[0-9]\+\).*/\1/p'
```

this will print out only the revision e.g. `r1234`

If you need only the number of the revision use

```
  svn log --limit 1 | sed -n -e 's/^r\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p'
```

UPDATE: to store it in a variable use

bash:

```
REVISION=$(svn log --limit 1 | sed -n -e 's/^r\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p')
```

tcsh

```
  set revision = `svn log --limit 1 | sed -n -e 's/^r\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p'`
```

Comment: This answers one part of my question. But how do I store the result in a shell variable?

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
svn blahblah |awk 'NR==2{print $1;exit;}'
```

test:

```
kent$  echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------
r91525 | plugin-master | 2009-02-03 10:39:23 +0530 (Tue, 03 Feb 2009) | 1 line

adding bulk-delete by sudar
------------------------------------------------------------------------"|awk 'NR==2{print $1;exit;}'
r91525
```

Comment: This answers one part of my question. But how do I store the result in a shell variable?

Comment: @Sudar try `var=$(svn  ...|awk ...)` then echo $var you should see the value was stored.

Comment: This works, but I am accepting the other answer since he also gave the tcsh version. Upvoted though ..