# How to get svn repository previous commit number

Tags: svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access the current Subversion build number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110175/how-to-access-the-current-subversion-build-number)

How can I get hold of my previous commit number that I have committed to?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`svn log | grep '$USER' | head -2 | cut -d' ' -f1 | tail -1` works for me:

```
{Z} hd1: 15:50 % svn log | grep 'cutting' | head -2 | cut -d' ' -f1 | tail -1 
r421185
```