# Make failing because of call to git while the project was moved from Git to SVN

Tags: git, svn, makefile

The project I am trying to compile was previously in a Git repository and compiled by calling `make` in Ubuntu Linux terminal. Now I'm moving the project to a Subversion repository and when I call `make` from the terminal, an error appears:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /home)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set). 
FWVersion: 0.00-re8k-hal-2014-08-15 
BuildTag:
```

This is very interesting given the fact `make` wasn't supposed to be a repository-directed tool! I did some research on the make files and I did manage to find the word `git` in one of the files; I guess that's the dependency that is causing me problems.

The real problem, though, is that I have no idea how to edit makefiles and, therefore, how to correct this problem (and this presupposing that the problem is this `git` mention in the makefiles).

## Makefile

```
include Makerules.mk

export PATH := $(TGT_GCC_PATH):$(PATH)

printversions:
    @echo FWVersion: ${FIRWMARE_VERSION}
    @echo BuildTag: ${BUILDTAG}
    @echo

dev_test:
    make -f ../build/MakeDevTest.mk -I./ all

dev_test_lib:
    make -f ../build/MakeDevTest.mk -I./ all_no_tests

dev_lib:
    make -f ../build/MakeDevLib.mk -I./ all

tgt_lib:
    make -f ../build/MakeTgtLib.mk -I./ all

tgt_test:
    make -f ../build/MakeTgtTest.mk -I./ all_no_tests


all: printversions tgt_lib tgt_test dev_lib dev_test_lib dev_test

install: tgt_lib tgt_test dev_lib dev_test_lib
    @mkdir -p ../../common/lib
    cp lib/libhal* ../../common/lib
    @mkdir -p ../../common/include
    @rm ../../common/include/hal -rf
    cp src/hal ../../common/include/ -r
    @mkdir -p ../../sdcard_files/defaultFiles/bin/tests
    cp $(TARGET)-tgt-test ../../sdcard_files/defaultFiles/bin/tests/$(TARGET)-test

clean:
    make -f ../build/MakeDevTest.mk -I./ clean
    make -f ../build/MakeDevLib.mk -I./ clean
    make -f ../build/MakeTgtTest.mk -I./ clean
    make -f ../build/MakeTgtLib.mk -I./ clean
    @rm lib -rf
```

## Makerules.mk

```
BUILDTAG = $(shell git describe --all --long | tr "-" " " | awk '{ print $$2 "-" $$3 }')
FIRWMARE_VERSION = $(shell cat lib_version.txt)-$(shell date --iso)
TGT_LINUX_INCLUDE_DIR = $(shell cat ../../host_cfg/linux-tgt-include-dir.txt)

### TOOL CHAIN ###

CC=cc
AR=ar
STRIP=strip

TGT_GCC_PATH = $(shell cat ../../host_cfg/gcc-tgt-path.txt)

TGT_CC= arm-arago-linux-gnueabi-gcc
TGT_AR= arm-arago-linux-gnueabi-ar
TGT_STRIP= arm-arago-linux-gnueabi-strip
TGT_LD= arm-arago-linux-gnueabi-ld

### SOURCES ###

SOURCE_FOLDER = src

SRC_DIRS = \
    src/comm \
    src

TEST_SRC_DIRS = \
    test/mocks \
    test/comm \
    test

### PROJECT ###

TARGET = hal

### TEST FRAMEWORK ###

CPPUTEST_HOME = ../../common/CppUTest

### C FLAGS ###

ALL_CCPPFLAGS   = -Isrc -I ../../common/include -D AUTO_GEN_BUILD_TAG='"${BUILDTAG}"' -D AUTO_GEN_FIRWMARE_VERSION='"${FIRWMARE_VERSION}"' -g -fPIC -I../../kernel/packages/linux/include
ALL_CONLYFLAGS = -std=gnu99
ALL_CPPONLYFLAGS  =
TEST_CFLAGS  = -I$(CPPUTEST_HOME)/include/ -D SYSTEM_UNIT_TEST -D DEBUG
DEV_CCPPFLAGS   = -D DEV
TGT_CCPPFLAGS   = -D TGT -I $(TGT_LINUX_INCLUDE_DIR) 

### LINKER LIBS AND FLAGS ###
DEV_STATIC_LIBS      = 
TGT_STATIC_LIBS      =  
DEV_TEST_STATIC_LIBS =  ../../common/lib/libchelper-dev-test.a 
TGT_TEST_STATIC_LIBS =  ../../common/lib/libchelper-tgt-test.a 

DEV_SHARED_LIBS_PATH     = 
DEV_SHARED_LIBS          = -lzmq -lm -lpthread
TGT_SHARED_LIBS_PATH     = -L ../../sdcard_files/defaultFiles/lib
TGT_SHARED_LIBS          = -lzmq -lm -lpthread

DEV_LDFLAGS     =
TGT_LDFLAGS     =
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem causing `fatal: Not a git repository…` is definitely call to `git` command. You have only one call to `git` in your example and that is when setting `BUILDTAG` variable in `Makerules.mk`:

```
BUILDTAG = $(shell git describe --all --long | tr "-" " " | awk '{ print $$2 "-" $$3 }')
```

You use `BUILDTAG`

- in `printversion` target in `Makefile`, where you just `echo` it to the terminal, and
- when setting `ALL_CCPPFLAGS` variable in `Makerules.mk`:

  ```
  ALL_CCPPFLAGS   = -Isrc -I ../../common/include -D AUTO_GEN_BUILD_TAG='"${BUILDTAG}"' -D AUTO_GEN_FIRWMARE_VERSION='"${FIRWMARE_VERSION}"' -g -fPIC -I../../kernel/packages/linux/include
  ```

From its name and contents, I assume that `ALL_CCPPFLAGS` contains GCC parameters. Option `-D` defines the a preprocessor macro in GCC, `AUTO_GEN_BUILD_TAG` in this case. You can find its use in the source files and decide if the macro is still needed.

If it is not, remove all its uses, remove `-D AUTO_GEN_BUILD_TAG='"${BUILDTAG}"'` from the definition of `ALL_CCPPFLAGS`, delete the line with `BUILDTAG` and delete the line in `Makefile` where it is `echo`ed.

If it is still needed, you have to set its contents otherwise. `$(shell …)` executes `…` in a shell, probably Bash. (For more info see [`info make shell`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html).) The `git describe` command finds the most recent tag reachable from the branch you are currently on (HEAD). `--all` enables search even in objects that are not *true tags*. `--long` ensures the format of output. Quoting Git 1.7.2.3 manual:

```
--long
    Always output the long format (the tag, the number of commits and
    the abbreviated commit name) even when it matches a tag. This is
    useful when you want to see parts of the commit object name in
    "describe" output, even when the commit in question happens to be a
    tagged version. Instead of just emitting the tag name, it will
    describe such a commit as v1.2-0-gdeadbee (0th commit since tag
    v1.2 that points at object deadbee....).
```

From `v1.2-0-gdeadbee` in the example, the `tr … | awk …` pipeline would make `0-gdeadbee`, that is number of commits since last tag, hyphen, letter g and first seven characters of the ID of the object the tag points to.

From here on, you are on your own. How to adapt the `AUTO_GEN_BUILD_TAG` value depends on its use and on how you are going to assign version numbers now. SVN uses a different version number convention. If you know how to get its value in shell, just paste the pipeline in the `BUILDTAG` definition in place of the original command (`…` in `BUILDTAG = $(shell …)`). Just be sure to double all dollar signs because otherwise they will be interpreted as make variables.

Comment: thanks for the reply! It goes directly to the point, and the only thing lacking for my chosen solution (which is not to cut away BUILDTAG, only to change it for SVN style) is the commands to be put in `...`. Fortunately, this has already being addressed here on SO in links such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579196/getting-the-last-revision-number-in-svn , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56227/how-do-you-determine-the-latest-svn-revision-number-rooted-in-a-directory and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110175/how-to-access-the-current-subversion-build-number#112674.

Comment: I was not sure if SVN revision number is what you wanted, @Momergil. It depends on how you use the string. If some code was relying on its structure, code for getting SVN revision number would not have been the answer you wanted. I’m glad you managed to fill in the last missing piece of the puzzle yourself! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `BUILDTAG = $(shell git describe --all --long | tr "-" " " | awk '{ print $$2 "-" $$3 }')` line is likely your problem.

You need to come up with some other way to define that make variable and use that there (or remove the variable entirely if you don't need it anymore).