# SVN info latest commit in trunk

Tags: svn

If I type

```
svn info|grep Revision
```

I get the latest revision in all branches, but how do I get the latest commit only in the main trunk?

Answer (score 2):

It's `svn info <URL-to-trunk> -r HEAD`

"-r HEAD" part is not really required because `svn info` shows the most recent commit made to the specified version of the object by default.

See [SVNBook | `svn info`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html).

Answer (score 1):

I found it here: [How do you determine the latest SVN revision number rooted in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56227/how-do-you-determine-the-latest-svn-revision-number-rooted-in-a-directory/249905#249905)

```
svnversion -c /path/to/your-projects-local-working-copy/. | sed -e 's/[MS]//g' -e 's/^[[:digit:]]*://'
```