# How to get the 'BASE' number with 'svn info' command by 'find' filter in Windows batch file?

Tags: batch-file, svn

I want to get the 'BASE' number by 'svn info' command in Windows batch file as the following batch script:

```
svn update

for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('svn info -rBASE^|find "Revision"') do (
 @echo %%i
 set svn_rev=%%i
)
```

But I always got the 'HEAD' number of my svn managed project code. So I tried the command directly in console:

```
>svn info -rBASE
Path: AliceAgent4.0b5856
URL: https://192.168.1.116:3443/svn/ProjectAliceVR/AliceOperationAgent/branches/AliceAgent4.0b5856
Relative URL: ^/AliceOperationAgent/branches/AliceAgent4.0b5856
Repository Root: https://192.168.1.116:3443/svn/ProjectAliceVR
Repository UUID: 794566ed1-6640e-7746-860d-66136dce9e99a
Revision: 5936
Node Kind: directory
Last Changed Author: yuanhui.he
Last Changed Rev: 5933
Last Changed Date: 2019-03-21 15:10:43 +0800 (周四, 21 3月 2019)
```

The `Revision` is `5936`, other than `5933`. Then, I tried the `HEAD` parameter of `svn`, it output the same result with `BASE`:

```
> svn info -rHEAD
Path: AliceAgent4.0b5856
URL: https://192.168.1.116:3443/svn/ProjectAliceVR/AliceOperationAgent/branches/AliceAgent4.0b5856
Relative URL: ^/AliceOperationAgent/branches/AliceAgent4.0b5856
Repository Root: https://192.168.1.116:3443/svn/ProjectAliceVR
Repository UUID: 794566ed1-6640e-7746-860d-66136dce9e99a
Revision: 5936
Node Kind: directory
Last Changed Author: yuanhui.he
Last Changed Rev: 5933
Last Changed Date: 2019-03-21 15:10:43 +0800 (周四, 21 3月 2019)
```

EDIT:

I have tried `'svn info -rBASE^|find "Last Changed Rev:"'` but it only got a `Changed` string in the batch script.

So, how can I get the number `5933` in the `Last Changed Rev: 5933` line?

Comment: Change the number of `tokens` and the string to `find`. Possible duplicate of [How do you determine the latest SVN revision number rooted in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56227/how-do-you-determine-the-latest-svn-revision-number-rooted-in-a-directory)

Comment: I have seen your edit, it appears that you've not use the advice from my previous comment regarding changing the `tokens` or the code shown in the linked duplicate, which contains at least one `For /F` loop using the appropriate string to `find` and correct number of `tokens`.

Comment: @Compo Because I'm trying your linked answer and find some useful information. Basically, these are two way to solve this issue.

Comment: I suggest to stay with `tokens=2` but use `delims=:` and then do a `set /a svn_rev=%%i` to get rid of the leading space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, there are two issues in this question:

- How to get the `COMMITTED` number other than the `HEAD` number.
- How to correct the `find` parameter in a Windows batch file to find the correct result.

Honestly, the question [How do you determine the latest SVN revision number rooted in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56227/how-do-you-determine-the-latest-svn-revision-number-rooted-in-a-directory) is not fixed my issue but some body answered my question.

I think anybody find my issue here because they are facing the same questions with me. Omit time for them is always valuable, so I arranged answers here:

A1: change `BASE` or `HEAD` to `COMMITTED` can directly get you wants:

```
svn update

for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('svn info -rCOMMITTED^|find "Revision"') do (
 @echo %%i
 set svn_rev=%%i
)
```

A2: change the `for` loop's `tokens` value to `4`, then change the `find` parameter to `Last Changed Rev:`. This can correct the action of the `for` loop to find the correct number. I'm not familiar with windows batch scrip, my fault, @Compo.

```
svn update

for /f "tokens=4" %%i in ('svn info -rHEAD^|find "Last Changed Rev:"') do (
 @echo %%i
 set svn_rev=%%i
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment,

- split the input at the colon
- using simulated input per text file
- use findstr with it's RegEx features `^` anchor at line begin and multiple search strings
- set variable name from start of line (with spaces removed) and
- use set /A to remove trailing space from number
  (might fail with 08xx/09xx being interpreted as octal)

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\03\22\SO_55291828.cmd
@Echo off&Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

::svn update

Echo svn info -rBASE
for /f "tokens=1-2delims=:" %%i in ('
  type svn_info-rBASE ^|findstr "^Last.Changed.Rev ^Revision"
') do (
 Set "var=%%i"
 set /A "_!var: =!=%%j"
)
Set _
Echo:
Echo svn info -rHEAD
for /f "tokens=1-2delims=:" %%i in ('
  type svn_info-rHEAD ^|findstr "^Last.Changed.Rev ^Revision"
') do (
 Set "var=%%i"
 set /A "_!var: =!=%%j"
)
Set _
```

Sample output:

```
> SO_55291828.cmd
svn info -rBASE
_LastChangedRev=5933
_Revision=5936

svn info -rHEAD
_LastChangedRev=5933
_Revision=5936
```