# Subclipse: add revision no in file

Tags: c, svn, compiler-construction

Is there a possibility to insert the revision no of a file in the file.

For example in the description or in a string. Maybe there is a kind of preprocessor command.

Comment: You mean the SVN revision number?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the subversion repository number into code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248/getting-the-subversion-repository-number-into-code)

Comment: @ Constantinus:  I mean the revision number of my C file (for example)

Comment: Note: I need a `C` solution ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer this way:

in your C file:

```
#define SVN_FULL_REV "$Id$"
#define SVN_REV "$Revision$"
```

Then do:

```
svn propset svn:keywords 'Id Revision' yourfile.c
```

Everytime you commit or update the file, `SVN_REV` will be your revision ID and `SVN_FULL_REV` the entire info string like `"$Id: xxx.c 78 2012-09-04 08:42:34Z Author $"`.

Comment: That's nearly exact what I searched for. But SVN_REV is then something like that `"$Id: xxx.c 78 2012-09-04 08:42:34Z Author $"` It would be nice just to have the Revision no. That would be no problem with c++ (substr) but so far as I know is no function like that available in C.

Comment: Then you have to use `$Revision$` instead of `$Id$`. I'll update my answer.